# How do I make Linux run a foreign program (almost) as if native

Tags: linux

I read, some years ago, that you could get linux to invoke the `java` command to run java programs by adding a bit of linux magic, but I can't remember how to do it or where I read it.

Back then I got it working and, if I recall correctly, it was fairly easy to do; just tell linux to use `java` to run `.jar` or similar files. I believe I also got it to run powerpc binaries, through qemu, using the same technique. Naturally, you would still have to mark them as exeutable.

I am not talking running `java java_program_to_run` or using some shell script that will, essentially, just call the same command. Nor am I asking for a way to convert a java program to an x86 binary for any particular operating system.

It was a technique that would allow Linux to deal with exectuables that wheren't native to the system, almost, as if they where native (some simulation required).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc

Comment: @davmac Make that an answer and add a few details, and you've got my acceptance.

Comment: I've no time to write an answer right now, but feel free to take it and write your own answer (I won't be offended), or wait for someone else to write a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to checkout [binfmt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html).  More specifically, follow the instructions for [java](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/java.html).  I realize the usual practice is to copy the details into the answer, but they're quite long and it doesn't feel right to copy-and-paste the whole thing into the answer.